# How to render components with query strings React-Router

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

CodeSandbox — [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1y9z905x2l)

I'm trying to render components with `react-router`, but I don't understand correctly how to work with query strings. So condition — if `?tbm=first` ⟹ it'll render first component and so on. How to do this?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A different query string doesn't form a different path. In your example, the path is always the same, i.e. `/search`, so routing cannot differentiate between your components.

If you amend your code to have three actual paths (`/first`, `/second` and `/third`) and amend the links accordingly, then your code works as intended, [see](https://codesandbox.io/s/3xqq1r06jq)

If you want to switch on the query string, you have to stick to a single Route with path `/search` and display your component object based on the parsed querystring, [see](https://codesandbox.io/s/5x64nq5xkn)

Comment: Thank you very much for a detail answer!

Answer (score 3):

The query string will be available inside `this.props.location.search` inside your rendered component. So the idea is you need to have a parent component which gets rendered something like this.

```
<Route path="/" component={parentComponent} />
```

Now whatever you enter as query string will be available and you can see that if you crack open your react dev tool. And once you have this string just parse it and have dynamic routes based on your custom condition.
check out image for your reference.[image]